# How do I export my Google+ pictures?

Tags: google-plus, images, export

I'm starting the process of leaving Google+, but have a couple of large albums there that I'd like to save (so, going to each picture and saving it individually would be very painful).  Exporting the whole set of albums to local files would be fine, since I can do anything with them then.  A direct export from Google into Facebook would also be fine, since that's where I'll probably put them initially.

How do I accomplish an export of pictures from Google+?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can download everything via https://www.google.com/settings/takeout

1. Click the blue `Create an archive` button
2. Uncheck the `Select all` checkbox to uncheck everything, and then check just the `Google Photos` box.
3. You can click on `Edit` on this line, but the default is to download all your albums.
4. Click the red `Create Archive` button.
5. Wait

You'll receive email when the archive is prepared and you'll then be able to download this archive.

Comment: 2 Excellent answers so far.  I prefer this one slightly as it goes above and beyond and offers the capability to easily extract ALL my Google+ data!

Comment: Thanks! This answer also works with the new Google Photos that was released in May 2015.

Comment: Does this include the photo descriptions? I notice that if I add a photo description, then download that single photo individually using that photo's 'download' button, then the description I added is not included in the file's metadata fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can download all your albums using http://picasa.google.com/. Alternatively you can use https://www.google.com/takeout.